# AJAX request to .php file returns empty string

Tags: php, ajax

First: I am new to **AJAX** and just know some basics about **PHP**.

I want to do an **AJAX** post to a **.php** file. To do that I got this code:

```
var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
var lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyPostalCodes',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {lat: lat, lng: lng, radius: 20, maxRows: 100, country: 'CH', username: 'bbag8274'},
    success: function(scriptData, textStatus, jqXHR){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'privatkunden_data.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {xmldata: jqXHR.responseText, address: $('#address').val()},
            success: function(secondScriptData, textStatus, jqXHR){
                alert('suc');
            },

            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert(jqXHR.responseText);
            }
        });                         
    },

    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert('fail');
    }
});
```

If the first post is successful it executes the second one. But the second one executes the **error:** function. Here is my **.php** file:

```
$xmlroot = $_POST['xmldata'];

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadXML($xmlroot);

foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('postalcode') as $postalcode){
    $zipcodes = $postalcode->nodeValue . " ";
}
```

The problem is: The **AJAX** post returns an empty alert box (`alert(jqXHR.responseText);`) and the **.php** file returns an error:

```
 **PHP Warning:  DOMDocument::loadXML(): Empty string supplied as input**
```

So the error says my `$xmlroot` variable is empty, am I right? If yes, why is it empty? It should be filled in with informations from `xmldata`.

Suggestions are appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't do ajax requests to domains that are not the current one unless you use jsonp. Check out Wikipedias article on [Same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean. I can't do it in this way? Thanks for the link, I will check it

Comment: what is the lat and lng ?

Comment: I mean. Give us the real value of lat and lng. This way is gonna be easier for testing.

Comment: lat & lng are some coordinates. For example you can use `lat=47.644200` and `lng=9.180260`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data in the first ajax call is coming right. Try to put the dataType as text and convert this text to xml on your PHP.

```
dataType: 'text'
```

Example:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyPostalCodes',
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'text',
    data: {lat: '47.644200', lng: '9.180260', radius: 20, maxRows: 100, country: 'CH', username: 'bbag8274'},
    success: function(result){
      alert(result)
    }
});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/t5jA5/

Comment: That didn't help :/ If I add dataType it doesn't load anymore

Comment: Mh okay. Then I've something other wrong in my code. I will look at it again and try to fix it. This answer is the correct answer to a code which **works**

Comment: After changing try to convert the XML on your PHP

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that you specify POST parameters although you do a GET request?

change the URL in something like

```
http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyPostalCodes?lat=47&lng=9&username=demo
```

...and read : http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html

Comment: If I use GET I have all the parameters in the `data:{}` function and if I use POST I have all the parameters in the `url:` function. It shouldn't matter what I use. The only difference is that with GET the user will see the url and with POST not. Or am I totally wrong with this comment? :)

Comment: ok. sorry you're right . But something else is not right in the data line. Shouldn't it read
data: '{"lat": 47.644200, "lng": 9.18026, "radius": 20, "maxRows": 100, "country": "CH", "username": "bbag8274"}',

Comment: Yeah that is what it reads. And this is successful but the second post isn't successful. Because in the second AJAX post it executes the error function and not the success function